# Build fail for Windows platform Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

StackOverflow community,

I have already made builds for macOS, iOS, and for Android, and also published them to these platforms without any issues.

But now I am trying to make Windows build for the first time and getting errors. Please, help to understand what these errors means?

Also tell me, in these Windows logs, what should I look at to understand what the error is about? There are so many things here that I can’t understand where to look and what to analyze.

```
Process terminated. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Immutable.DisposableEnumeratorAdapter`2.Dispose()
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.Union(IEnumerable`1 other, MutationInput origin)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.Union(IEnumerable`1 items, Boolean avoidWithComparer)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.WithComparer(IEqualityComparer`1 equalityComparer)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundDecisionDag.get_ReachableLabels()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.CheckSwitchErrors(SwitchStatementSyntax node, BoundExpression boundSwitchGoverningExpression, ImmutableArray`1& switchSections, BoundDecisionDag decisionDag, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.BindSwitchStatementCore(SwitchStatementSyntax node, Binder originalBinder, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindSwitchStatement(SwitchStatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(StatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlockParts(BlockSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlock(BlockSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(StatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(CSharpSyntaxNode declaration, BlockSyntax blockBody, ArrowExpressionClauseSyntax expressionBody, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(CSharpSyntaxNode syntax, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.BindMethodBody(MethodSymbol method, TypeCompilationState compilationState, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics, VariableState nullableInitialState, ImportChain& importChain, Boolean& originalBodyNested, InitialState& forSemanticModel)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileMethod(MethodSymbol methodSymbol, Int32 methodOrdinal, ProcessedFieldInitializers& processedInitializers, SynthesizedSubmissionFields previousSubmissionFields, TypeCompilationState compilationState)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileNamedType(NamedTypeSymbol containingType)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CompileNamedTypeAsync>b__0()
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FailFast.OnFatalException(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FatalError.Report(System.Exception, System.Action`1<System.Exception>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FatalError.ReportAndPropagate(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FatalError.ReportAndPropagateUnlessCanceled(System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CompileNamedTypeAsync>b__0()
   at System.Collections.Immutable.DisposableEnumeratorAdapter`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1+Enumerator[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], System.Collections.Immutable, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]].Dispose()
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Union(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, MutationInput<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Union(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, Boolean)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].WithComparer(System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundDecisionDag.get_ReachableLabels()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.CheckSwitchErrors(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SwitchStatementSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundExpression, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundSwitchSection> ByRef, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundDecisionDag, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.BindSwitchStatementCore(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SwitchStatementSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindSwitchStatement(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SwitchStatementSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.StatementSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlockParts(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.BlockSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlock(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.BlockSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.StatementSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.BlockSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ArrowExpressionClauseSyntax, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxNode, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.BindMethodBody(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.MethodSymbol, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.TypeCompilationState, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BindingDiagnosticBag, VariableState, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.ImportChain ByRef, Boolean ByRef, InitialState ByRef)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileMethod(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.MethodSymbol, Int32, ProcessedFieldInitializers ByRef, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SynthesizedSubmissionFields, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.TypeCompilationState)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileNamedType(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.NamedTypeSymbol)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CompileNamedTypeAsync>b__0()
   at Roslyn.Utilities.UICultureUtilities+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<WithCurrentUICulture>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<.cctor>b__284_0(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef, System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntryUnsafe(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteFromThreadPool(System.Threading.Thread)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.Thread+StartHelper.RunWorker()
   at System.Threading.Thread+StartHelper.Run()
   at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Collections.Immutable.DisposableEnumeratorAdapter`2.Dispose()
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.Union(IEnumerable`1 other, MutationInput origin)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.Union(IEnumerable`1 items, Boolean avoidWithComparer)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet`1.WithComparer(IEqualityComparer`1 equalityComparer)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.BoundDecisionDag.get_ReachableLabels()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.CheckSwitchErrors(SwitchStatementSyntax node, BoundExpression boundSwitchGoverningExpression, ImmutableArray`1& switchSections, BoundDecisionDag decisionDag, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SwitchBinder.BindSwitchStatementCore(SwitchStatementSyntax node, Binder originalBinder, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindSwitchStatement(SwitchStatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(StatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlockParts(BlockSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindBlock(BlockSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindStatement(StatementSyntax node, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(CSharpSyntaxNode declaration, BlockSyntax blockBody, ArrowExpressionClauseSyntax expressionBody, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Binder.BindMethodBody(CSharpSyntaxNode syntax, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.BindMethodBody(MethodSymbol method, TypeCompilationState compilationState, BindingDiagnosticBag diagnostics, VariableState nullableInitialState, ImportChain& importChain, Boolean& originalBodyNested, InitialState& forSemanticModel)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileMethod(MethodSymbol methodSymbol, Int32 methodOrdinal, ProcessedFieldInitializers& processedInitializers, SynthesizedSubmissionFields previousSubmissionFields, TypeCompilationState compilationState)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.CompileNamedType(NamedTypeSymbol containingType)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.MethodCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CompileNamedTypeAsync>b__0()
```

Comment: You need to learn [how to debug](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: Make sure everything is up to date